# Application giving error while trying to run

Tags: android

I am developing an android application where i have no errors in the code.But when i try to run the android application it shows the error message listed below

VMSApplication] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0. Please fix project properties.

Has anyone faced this problem before,,

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this(if you are using Eclipse)

```
First: Package Explorer ->Right click the project ->“Android Tools” -> “Fix Project Properties”

Then Restart Eclipse: "File" -> “Restart”
```

if that doesn't work

try setting the compatibility level

`"Window/Preferences", "Java/Compiler/Compiler Compliance Level"`

Comment: Assuming OP is using Eclipse.